# Why is powershell changing the variable data? Can i make it stop?

Tags: powershell

My script takes the content of 2 files, which have an id in the first element of each line. I'm trying to take the id of each line in file 1, find a matching line in file 2, then compare the file 1 line to the file 2 line. If they are different, that difference will be sent to a database file to update. For some reason, the variables holding my data just decide to not hold data anymore. In the following example, the CompareData loses the value of $web and $data, sometime after the first if ($web -match) statement.

```
function CompareData($web, $data)
{
    $webs = $web -split "@@@"
    $datas = $data -split "@@@"
    if ($web -match "1862185823")
    {
      write-host "$web"
      ###this will display the full line of the web file, and was only 
      #added to show what i'm talking about
    }
##########################The value of web seems to break sometime after these
##########################variable declarations.
    $wid = $webs[0];$wit = $webs[1];$wst = $webs[2];$wpr = $webs[3];$won = $webs[4];$wsd = $webs[5];$wtd = $webs[6];$wcd = $webs[7];$weh = $webs[8];$wdh = $webs[9];$wah = $webs[10];$wac = $webs[11];$wpd = $webs[12]
    $did = $datas[0];$dit = $datas[1];$dst = $datas[2];$dpr = $datas[3];$don = $datas[4];$dsd = $datas[5];$dtd = $datas[6];$dcd = $datas[7];$deh = $datas[8];$ddh = $datas[9];$dah = $datas[10];$dac = $datas[11];$dpd = $datas[12]
    $wehstr = [string]$weh;$wdhstr = [string]$wdh;$wahstr = [string]$wah;$dehstr = [string]$deh;$dahstr = [string]$dah;$ddhstr = [string]$ddh
    $wdCount = $wit.Length / 2
    $dtCount = $wit.Length / 2
    $newWtitle = $wit.Substring(0, $wdCount)
    $newDtitle = $dit.Substring(0, $dtCount)
    if ($web -match "1862185823")
    {

        #the actual contents of $web are now wrong!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }
    if ($wehstr.Length -gt $dehstr.Length){$dehstr = $dehstr.PadRight($dehstr.Length + 1, "0")}
    if ($wdhstr.Length -gt $ddhstr.Length){$ddhstr = $ddhstr.PadRight($ddhstr.Length + 1, "0")}
    if ($wahstr.Length -gt $dahstr.Length){$dahstr = $dahstr.PadRight($dahstr.Length + 1, "0")}
    if ($dehstr.Length -gt $wehstr.Length){$wehstr = $wehstr.PadRight($wehstr.Length + 1, "0")}
    if ($dahstr.Length -gt $wahstr.Length){$wahstr = $wahstr.PadRight($wahstr.Length + 1, "0")}
    if ($ddhstr.Length -gt $wdhstr.Length){$wdhstr = $wdhstr.PadRight($wdhstr.Length + 1, "0")}

    if ($newWtitle -match $newDtitle -and $wehstr -match $dehstr -and $wahstr -match $dahstr -and $ddhstr -match $wdhstr -and $wsd -match $dsd -and $wtd -match $dtd -and $wcd -match $dcd -and $won -match $don -and $wst -match $dst -and $wpr -match $dpr -and $wac -match $dac -and $wpd -match $dpd)
    {
        #write-host "$wid and $did match"
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "they didn't match"
    }
    $wid = "";$wit = "";$wst = "";$wpr = "";$won = "";$wsd = "";$wtd = "";$wcd = "";$weh = "";$wdh = "";$wah = "";$wac = "";$wpd = "";
    $did = "";$dit = "";$dst = "";$dpr = "";$don = "";$dsd = "";$dtd = "";$dcd = "";$deh = "";$ddh = "";$dah = "";$dac = "";$dpd = "";
    $webs = ""
    $datas = ""
}

$dc = gc "${DatabaseFile}"
$wc = gc "${WebFile}"
write-host "Started"
foreach ($w in $wc)
{
    try
    {
        $x = 0
        $ws = $w -split "@@@"#custom delimiter since people are using tabs pipes and everything else in the titles....
        $webid = $ws[0]

        $result = select-string -Path "${DatabaseFile}" -pattern $webid

        if ($result -ne $null)
        {

            $newresult = $result -replace "D\:\\phi\\phs\\Oversight\\Projects\\Database.txt:\d{1,}:", ""
            $doublecheck = $newresult -split "@@@"
            if ($doublecheck[0] -eq $webid)
            {


                CompareData $w $newresult


            }
            else
            {
                write-host "Found a mismatch id, searching individual records line by line for a matching id"
                foreach ($d in $dc)#this slow method is only called when someone has another ID in the title in addition to the
                {#first element which is also id. Select-string grabs a match in the entire document, so this is here for single
                #searching each record for a matching id in the first element
                    $ds = $d -split "@@@"
                    $did = $ds[0]
                    $found = 0
                    if ($did -eq $webid)
                    {
                        CompareData $w $d
                        $found = 1
                        break
                    }
                    if ($found -eq 0)
                    {
                        write-host "Added $w to Insert file"
                        $w|out-file -append "${InsertFile}"
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "Added $w to Insert file"
            $w|out-file -append "${InsertFile}"
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: So i ran this first part to where you said it had diffrent data. It doesnt do that for me. Maybe you need to walk through it using ISE or VSCode and see whats happening. I cant reproduce your issue.  I would first try just killing the powershell console or IDE and reopening it to clear all the variables and see what happens.

Comment: Just a hint on your variable declarations, this can be simplified `$wid,$wit,$wst,$wpr,$won,$wsd,$wtd,$wcd,$weh,$wdh,$wah,$wac,$wpd = $webs[0..12]` The reset of the vars can also be shortened to `$wid=$wit=$wst=$wpr=$won=$wsd=$wtd=$wcd=$weh=$wdh=$wah=$wac=$wpd = "";`

Comment: no kidding? i'm guessing the compiler reads the multiple ='s as make each variable equal to, instead of make each variable = to that next listed variable

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the bug in this instance was with the lines

```
$wdCount = $wit.Length / 2
$dtCount = $wit.Length / 2
$newWtitle = $wit.Substring(0, $wdCount)
$newDtitle = $dit.Substring(0, $dtCount)
```

These actually take the length of the title element then halve it. I don't need an exact title comparison, just the first half of it's letters just incase someone did infact change the title completely. The new code has corrected this issue, and things are working again.

```
$wtl = $wit.length
$dtl = $dit.length
$sublength = 0
if ($wtl -ge $dtl)
{
    $sublength = $dtl / 2
}
else
{
    $sublength = $wtl / 2
}
$newWtitle = $wit.Substring(0, $sublength)
$newDtitle = $dit.Substring(0, $sublength)
```